# Android App Crashing While Trying To Parse Json Object Using Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

```
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Home.this);

    JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET ,"http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=avengers",null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                String Title = response.getString("Title");
                String Year = response.getString("Year");
                String Released = response.getString("Released");
                String Genre = response.getString("Genre");
                String Metascore = response.getString("Metascore");
                String imdbRating = response.getString("imdbRating");
                String Poster = response.getString("Poster");

                moviesData = new String[]{Title, Year, Released, Genre, Metascore, imdbRating, Poster};
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
```

I am trying to fetch data from the site and store its content using json parsing and volley i was doing it with HttpUrlConnection and it was working fine when i tried to do it using volley I got stuck
I don't know where I am going wrong or missing something don't know why App is crashing.

Comment: Show `response`

Comment: i don't think i am getting a response, tried to display the response and app crashed again,

Comment: at least  show crash logs to understand problem root

Comment: Thanks i am going to check it.

Comment: JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET ,"http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=avengers",new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()

You dont need null after URL

Comment: thank you so much found the error and removed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my own fault I was writing this code in the wrong method.